# Aria hack to assign a different heading to an html heading tag?

Tags: html, css, drupal, wai-aria

I am working within the constraints of a drupal CMS and I have no control over the font sizes for `h1, h2, h3`, etc.

We have been using `<h5>` because it is visually pleasing on the homepage.  But I do not want this `<h5>` content showing on screen readers.

I know I could add Inline CSS to the theme through Appearance --> Settings --> Advanced Options. Is it possible and accepted to use Aria to mask the `<h5>` content as `<p>` content?  How would I do this?  I have never seen `aria-level="0"`.  What level is invisible to screen readers?

My goal is to be able to use the different heading sizes graphically while still having them convey properly on screen readers.  IT is not interested in creating any new font size options.

Comment: Why can't you change the css? Are you the site content editor, not the developer? What base theme are you using? What version of Drupal?

Comment: There are around 100 sub-sites under that main site, which uses Drupal 8.8.6.  You are correct @2pha, I don't have admin privileges and even an admin could not change the css.  I can only do that through Appearance/Settings/Advanced/in-line CSS.